# Prove this refinement on the uniqueness of the identity element in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm doing a problem that asks me to prove the following refinement on the statement of the identity of a group.

---

**Problem Statement**

Let $G$ be a group with identity element $e$ and let $e', g \in G$. If $e'g = g$ then $e' = e$.

I know this statement is a refinement because the condition for identity has been relaxed to only require that an element act like the identity when multiplied by one element from one side. Rather than requiring for all $g \in G$, $e$ returns the element $g$ when multiplied from both sides.

---

**My attempt at a solution**

Let $e, e', g \in G$. We call $e$ the identity element because it satisfies $eg = ge = g$,  $\forall g \in G$. If $e'g = g$, then $e'g = eg$ and by cancellation we see that $e' = e$ and thus $e'$ is the identity element in $G$.

---

**Questions/Concerns**

My main concern is that I don't think I've really utilized the new conditions about only needing to be multiplied by *one* element on *one* side. My proof feels... lazy for lack of a better word but I'm a bit confused as to where these new, relaxed conditions come into play. Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing what axions you are free to use, it's hard to proceed.  "If you know there are right inverses then just right multiply both sides by the right inverse of $g$. " Does that work?

Comment: That's sort of what I was going with, with the cancellation, albeit less precise. I'm assuming that's the case since these are end-of-chapter questions and of course the existence/uniqueness of inverses are defined therein. Does the logic seem to make sense though? Equate these 2 elements (identity and element which acts like identity) by using inverses to cancel out the element $g$?

Comment: Again, it all comes down to the axioms.  If you are assuming the existence of right inverses, then the argument is valid.  If you are assuming something else, then the argument is incomplete.

Comment: It is best not to say "by cancellation" unless you have previously proved something by that name.  Instead, follow @lulu and say "multiply on the right by $g^{-1}$".

Comment: @lulu yes the existence of right inverses is given and allowed. Thank you for that important point: I will try to internalize the fact that I can't just assume that properties or results are allowed to be used and will be more careful with what I use and declaring it so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct, so not much to say about that. Let's instead talk about the feeling of laziness.

The point is you can *afford* to be lazy because of 'the group being a group', that what separates a group from more general 'sets with multiplication', is doing all the heavy lifting!

Compare for instance to the following statement:

> If for some 2-by-2 matrices $E$ and $G$ we have that $EG = G$ then $E$ equals the identity matrix

This statement if **false**. The trick to cooking up a counterexample is to take $G$ to be a matrix of which the the two columns are both scalar multiples of the same vector $v$ and to take $E$ to be any matrix for which $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.

Now while this statement about matrices is false, the statement in your question is true and that is because it demands $g$ to be taken from a group. If for instance we would repeat the statement about matrices, but would specify that we were talking solely about *invertible* matrices (which form a group) then the statement would be true. (And my counterexample would no longer be a counterexample as $G$'s of the form described are never invertible)

So in summary: if we want to tell apart the identity element in a group from the other elements we can use the 'lazy' definition involving only one other element $g$. If we want to tell apart the identity element in a larger set with multiplication then we need the 'full' definition of $eg = g$ *for all* $g$ because other elements $e'$ might satisfy $e'g = g$ for *specific* $g$.

A way to think about this in the context of more general (but still associative) multiplication is saying

> the identity element is the only element $e'$ so that $e'g = g$ for some invertible $g$.

Then depending on on how hard it is to find an example of en invertible element you can think about this characterization as more or as less lazy than the characterization involving $e'g = g$ for all $g$. (Of course in a group finding an invertible element is extremely easy as every element is invertible.)